# a simple condition went wrong?

Tags: python-3.x

I have checked a very basic condition but there is a strange result.

```py
print(sum([0.6, 0.3, 0.1]) == 1.0)
// false
print(sum([0.6, 0.3, 0.1]))
// 0.9999999999999999
```

Comment: use [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) for floats...

Comment: https://0.30000000000000004.com

Comment: But why does this behaviour happen?